# Pass a fold expression to a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

consider the following function that prints the arguments using fold expressions.

```
template <typename... T>
void print(T &&... t)
{
    (std::cout << ... << t) << '\n';
}
```

Consider a second function that calls it :

```
template <typename T, T... vals>
void call_print(std::integer_sequence<T, vals...> &&)
{
    print(vals...); //ok: prints 01234
}
call_print(std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
```

**In my use case, I need to call `print` this way (with a fold expression)**

```
template <typename T, T... vals>
void call_print2(std::integer_sequence<T, vals...> &&)
{
    print((vals, ...)); //not OK: only prints 4
}
call_print2(std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
```

In this case the call looks like this

```
print(0,(1,(2,(3,4))));
```

but the function seems to be only catching the last argument, as if I called it like so:

```
print(4);
```

any help would be appreciated

**EDIT: What I am actually trying to accomplish**

```
template<typename T, T ... ints>
auto make_seq(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...>&&)
{
   auto lambda = []<T val>()->T{/*implementation doesn't matter*/};
   return std::integer_sequence<T, (lambda.template operator()<ints>(), ...)>{}; //<- right here
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to print in reverse?

Comment: no, I want to pass a fold expression

Comment: You're folding over the comma operator, and therefore passing one argument to `print`.  That doesn't make any sense.  Can you give an example of what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean *pass a fold expression*. Could you show what `print` is supposed to look like?

Comment: I am updating the question right now

Comment: do you know what comma operator does? Do u know `std::cout << 0,(1,(2,(3,4)));` prints only zero

Comment: What do you want the call to output?

Comment: Just added some clarification

Comment: I'm struggling to understand as well, but do you maybe want to delay the evaluation of the fold expression? You could wrap it in a lambda and pass that to that end.

Comment: Or, if in your last snippet you want to end up with (pseudocode) `std::integer_sequence<T, lambda(ints[1]), lambda(ints[2]), ..., lambda(ints[n])>`, you just need to drop the parentheses and use a regular pack expansion rather than a fold expression.

Comment: huh ? what do you mean ? expand `ints` when calling the lambda ? that doesn't accomplish the same thing

Comment: I mean `std::integer_sequence<T, lambda.template operator()<ints>() ...>{};` (Edited for typo)

Comment: No really, [it works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oTek3teNWmP0Kt0S). But I'm still unsure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, it works fine, i didn't realize you edited for typo (`std::integer_sequence<T, lambda.template operator()<ints>(), ...>{};` was invalid). thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print((vals, ...))` expands to `print((0, 1, 2, 3, 4))`.  `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)` is an expression using the comma operator.  The comma operator evaluates both of its operands and discards the result of the left-hand side of the expression.  That means that the expression `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)` evaluates to the value `4`.  Thus `print((vals, ...))` is the same as `print((0, 1, 2, 3, 4))` is the same as `print(4)`.

In general, fold expressions are expressions, and thus evaluate to a single value.  You need to use a normal parameter pack expansion instead.  For example:

```
template<typename T, T... ints>
auto make_seq(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...>&&)
{
   auto lambda = []<T val>()->T{/*implementation doesn't matter*/};
   return std::integer_sequence<T, lambda.template operator()<ints>()...>{};
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e6918eb3cffea9)

Comment: any way to yield `print(0,1,2,3,4)` with a fold expression ?

Comment: @jbztt No.  Fold expressions are expressions and expand to produce expressions.  You want just a normal pack expansion.  Updated with an example.